# How to calculate YTD hours on a Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports

My company has a payroll program that prints payroll checks and pay stubs using Crystal Reports.  The report selects payroll data from a table that has these columns:  Hours, PeriodAmount, and YTDAmount.  The hours are based on payroll period ending date.  The report selects records based on a single pay period end date.  So, hours would be selected for a single pay period only.  However, we would like to print YTD hours on the pay stub.  In other words, hours accumulated from beginning of year to current pay period.  Since YTD hours is not a column in the table, would we need to include a sub report to accumulate hours?  I don't think running totals would work since we are selecting a single period only.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a subreport is one option.

Another option is to select all pay periods in the current year and compute the total for the current period using a conditional total. For example, create af ormula that returns the hours if the record belongs to the current period and zero otherwise. Then, SUM that formula per employee.  That SUM would give you the hours in the current period.